# SELECT operation using sqlsrv_query in php

Tags: php, sql, select

I am using following php code to select a max value from a table in MS sql server database.
This is just a snapshot of the code and not full code:

```
$sqlToCheckNID ="Select (?)=max(nid) from testRetailerlist";
$param_nid = array($maxNid,SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT);   
$maxNidInDb = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sqlToCheckNID,$param_nid); 
  echo "<li>" .$maxNid. "<li>";
```

Its throwing me error as `Undefined variable maxNid`

I want to echo the value that i get from the select statement. I think I am using the wrong syntax but could not found any example on net.

Comment: Try using isset.  See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your parameters' array as a third argument to `sqlsrv_query()`. You should also [pass the output parameters by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) after initializing them. So your your code  would be like this:

```
$maxNid = 0;
$sqlToCheckNID = "SELECT (?)=MAX(nid) FROM testRetailerlist";
$param_nid = array(&$maxNid, SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT);   
$maxNidInDb = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sqlToCheckNID, $param_nid);
echo "<li>" .$maxNid. "<li>";
```

For more information please consult [the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-query.php).

Comment: ohh i missed that. but am still getting the same error on adding too.m updating the question with the change

Comment: @user2129794, I have modified my answer.